# Rails/Angular database data not appearing after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am using the thinkster tutorial on Rails/Angular to create a reddit clone. The tutorial says that after including angular_rails_csrf into my Gemfile, I should see all of my posts on the home page even after refreshing the page. When I refresh the page, all the data is gone, but the data still remains because I can see all of my entries in my json. I am not sure what I did wrong, and was wondering if there is a way to fix this.

Here are some of my code:

posts.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.factory('posts', [
'$http', 
function($http) {
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };
    o.getAll = function() {
        return $http.get('/posts.json').success(function(data) {
            angular.copy(data, o.posts);
        });
    };

    o.create = function(post) {
        return $http.post('/posts.json', post).success(function(data) {
            o.posts.push(data);
        });
    };

    o.upvote = function(post) {
        return $http.put('/posts/' + post.id + '/upvote.json').success(function(data) {
            post.upvotes += 1;
        });
    };
}]);
```

app.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews',['ui.router', 'templates'])
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url:'/home',
        templateUrl:'home/_home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        resolve: {
            postPromise: ['posts', function(posts) {
                return posts.getAll();
            }]
        }
    })

    .state('posts', {
        url:'/posts/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'posts/_posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl',
        resolve: {
            post: ['$stateParams', 'posts', function($stateParams, posts) {
                return posts.get($stateParams.id);
            }]
        }
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])
```

mainCtrl.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'posts',
function($scope, posts) {

    $scope.posts = posts.posts;

    $scope.addPost=function() {
        if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') {
            alert("Post cannot be empty!");
            return;
        }
        posts.create({
            title: $scope.title,
            link: $scope.link,
        });
        $scope.title ='';
        $scope.link='';
    };

    $scope.incrementUpvotes=function(post) {
        posts.upvote(post);
    };
}]);
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with my HTML? Do I have to change anything in my HTML?